# NSPredicate to get all entities that their property matches one of few options

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an entity called "Contact", Every contact as a category property that holds a string with  category name. I wish to fetch only contacts from few of the categories.

For example I have few entities:

```
contact1.category = @"a";
contact2.category = @"b";
contact3.category = @"c";
contact4.category = @"c";
contact5.category = @"a";
```

Then I have this array of active categories:

```
self.selectedCategories = @[@"b",@"c"];
```

Now I want to fetch from core data only entities from @"a" and @"b".
Is that possible with an NSPredicate to pass to the fetch request?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? How does @"a" and @"b" correlate to `selectedCategories`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you!

```
NSPredicate *inPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"category IN %@", aCollection]; 
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```